# Wait for GitHub Actions workflow to finish before closing a PR

Tags: github-actions, pull-request

When merging to main, I have an action that runs to change the source attribute in Terraform files from a local path to Terraform Enterprise/Cloud URL. This is so we can test our code locally.

The action triggers on clicking `Merge pull request` > `Confirm merge` thus closing a PR from develop > main.

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - develop
    types: closed
```

This works fine, however, is there a way to stop the PR from actually closing until the action completes and if it fails, leave the PR open?

Or perhaps I can introduce another step, just before the PR is closed that triggers the action?

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Broxzier/1ed980b8b3822d213e98042fc6a92040) is the Gist I adapted.